# JSF redirect after session timeout always goes to login page

Tags: jsf, session, redirect, session-timeout

The thing is that I have a set of error pages, and I configured my application to use them, but after the session timeout occurs, it always goes to the login page, and after the user logs in, then the error page appears (which was supposed to appear before the login page).

Here is my authentication setup :

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SecurityConstraints</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyCollection</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/faces/web/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description />
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginFailed.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>All Users</description>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Which is supposed to include only the pages under /faces/web/, and it seems to work, since I can visit the errorpages without being logged in.

This is my file tree:

```
WebContent
   |
   errorpages/
   web/
   login.xhtml
   loginFailed.xhtml
```

I'm using JSF 2.2.8 with a WildFly 8 server

The error occurs after an asynchronus call which is handled by an ExceptionHandler:

```
package com.comanage.web.exceptions;

import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * A custom Exception Handler to give special treatment to any given  exception
 */
public class ViewExpiredExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

private ExceptionHandler wrapped;

public ViewExpiredExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
    this.wrapped = wrapped;
}

@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> iter = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Throwable exception = iter.next().getContext().getException();

        if (exception instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

            if(isAJAXRequest(request)) {
                String redirect = "/errorpages/expired.xhtml";
                System.out.println("An AJAX request has been detected after the view has expired: Redirecting to \""+redirect+"\"");
                String redirectURL = response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + redirect);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("<partial-response><redirect url=\"").append(redirectURL).append("\"></redirect></partial-response>");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                try {
                    pw = response.getWriter();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                pw.println(sb.toString());
                pw.flush();
            }
            else{
                facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "expiredview");
                facesContext.renderResponse();    
            }
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    getWrapped().handle();
}

@Override
public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
    return wrapped;
}

/**
 * Returns true is the request is an AJAX request
 * @param request An HttpServletRequest request
 * @return True if the request is an AJAX request
 */
private boolean isAJAXRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean check = false;
    String facesRequest = request.getHeader("Faces-Request");
    if (facesRequest != null && facesRequest.equals("partial/ajax")) {
        check = true;
    }
    return check;
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly was you doing on the secured page after the session has expired? Reloaded the page by GET? Or invoked a synchronous POST? Or an asynchronous POST? Is the behavior (redirect to login page) the same on all those actions?

Comment: I made an Ajax request, which I'm handling with a custom ExceptionHandler, I will add my exception handler to the question.

Comment: I see. To exclude further, please tell anyway the behavior on synchronous (non-ajax) POST request and when you reload the page by GET.

Comment: That's a good question, as soon as I have the chance, I will test those cases

Comment: For POST and GET requests it presents the exact same behavior